# Display queryset results by month in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Id like to group the results of my queryset in a table by month with the month name as a header for each table.

I have a model like so:

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contract_end = models.DateField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

View like so:

```
def expired_contracts(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    tenant_queryset = Tenant.objects.all()
    expired_list = []

    for x in range(0, 12):
        date = now + relativedelta(months=x)
        expired = tenant_queryset.filter(
            contract_end__year=date.year,
            contract_end__month=date.month
            )
        expired_list += expired

context = {"expired_list": expired_list}

return render(request, "expired_template.html", context)
```

Template:

```
{% for tenant in expired_list %}
<table>
<tr>
<td>{{ tenant.first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ tenant.telephone }}</td>
<td>{{ tenant.contract_end }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

I guess I could create a bunch of empty lists and populate them with a loop and if statements, but that seems a little much.

Any other way I could go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is an excellent tool for grouping your list.

First you should order your object by the attribute that you are grouping by

```
tenant_queryset = Tenant.objects.order_by('contract_end')
```

Grouping by month can be achieved by using `itertools.groupby` and formatting the date as the month's name as a string `date.strftime('%B')`

```
context = {
    "expired_list": itertools.groupby(
        expired_list, 
        lambda t: t.contract_end.strftime('%B')
    )
}
```

You can then loop over the months and the tenants for that month in the template like so

```
{% for month, tenants in expired_list %}
<h3>{{ month }}</h3>
<table>
    {% for tenant in tenants %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ tenant.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ tenant.telephone }}</td>
        <td>{{ tenant.contract_end }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Iain. Ive tried your method and it works. I managed to find another method as well using the regroup tag. Going to play around with itertools as well for future use

Comment: @OrangeBubbles - You should look into having just one query to get all the tenants with their contract expiring in the next 12 months. You can then pass this list into groupby or regroup and get the same results but with 1/12 the queries